# How to insert a triple line integral?

Tags: math-mode

A formula I want to typeset contains a tripple line integral, i.e. a symbol that has three integral signs that are encircled. How can I do this?

I tried `\oiiint`, but that does not work. `\iiint` works on the contrary.

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol. However, I can't find it myself using [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), but my mouse-drawing skills might be just to bad :-)

Comment: @Martin: [At the symbols link](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/symbols.html) you can find out that the symbol isn't supported by Detexify, but you can send an e-mail to Daniel Kirsch.

Comment: @Hendrik: Thanks, it seems that it doesn't support the whole `mathdesign` package yet.

Comment: \iiint works perfectly in Mathjax

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`mathdesign`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathdesign) package defines `\oiiint`, as do `txfonts` and `pxfonts` packages, according to the [comprehensive symbols list](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helpd. Unfortunately, this now requires a follow up question...