# How to use pxfonts with the standard KOMA Script font?

Tags: fonts, koma-script, sans-serif

In an [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13412/how-to-insert-a-triple-line-integral) I asked how to display a triple line integral. This was not possible with the earlier package `mathpazo` which I use, so I would like to switch to `pxfonts`. This package, if I understand it correctly, contains a set of different fonts of different families, including an extended Palatino that allows me to use the `\oiiint` command.

My earlier font combination was the standard KOMA Script sans serif font (forgot its name unfortunately) with Palatino as serif font, which fits nicely in my opinion.
 **How can I achieve the same combination using the `scrbook` class and the `pxfonts` package?**

Comment: So the question is "How do I switch back to the default serif font from KOMA script?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides redefining `\sfdefault`, as lockstep suggested, the math sans serif font should also be changed. Otherwise it would still be Helvetica.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{cmss}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{cmss}{bx}{n}
\begin{document}
\section{Text}
Text
\( \mathsf{Text} \)
\boldmath
\( \mathsf{Text} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: cmss with pxfonts]

Answer (score 8):

The `\sfdefault` macro defaults to `cmss` (Computer Modern Sans Serif) (or `lmss` in case you use the `lmodern` package). The `pxfonts` package redefines `\sfdefault` to `pxss` (Helvetica), and this needs to be undone.

EDIT: How did I find out about `cmss` and `pxss`? I put `\show\sfdefault` in the document preamble to display the definition of the `\sfdefault` macro (first with, then without loading `pxfonts`).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{pxfonts}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: could you say a little about how to find the code for a particular font like that? Say I wanted to use the sans font that the `libertine` package loads, how would I find that information?

Comment: @Seamus simply search for redefinitions of `\sfdefault` `$ grep -e "sfdefault" libertine.sty
   \renewcommand\sfdefault{\biolinum@param}%` followed by: `grep -e "biolinum@param" libertine.sty` delivers the font families: fxb, fxbj, fxbo, fxbjo