# Undefined control sequence \oiiint

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am trying to generate the triple integral in the following equation (The preamble is large, due to other requirements)

```
\documentclass[11pt,headings=small,fleqn]{scrreprt} % highest level is chapter
%\documentclass[12pt,journal,compsoc]{report}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap} %To add a rectangle at the beginning of each chapter
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel} % for English text only
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % for German text only
%\usepackage{ngerman}        % for German text only
\usepackage{mathtools}    %To split equations
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{mathdesign}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{microtype} % improves font spacing, needs pdfTEX >= 1.20
\usepackage{hyperref}  % hyperlinks

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{makeidx}    
\begin{flalign}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\oiiint \rho dv + \oiint \rho \stackrel{\rightarrow}{V}\cdot \stackrel{\rightarrow}{ss}=0
    \end{flalign}
```

But I keep getting the error `undefined control sequence \oiiint`

Can any one help please?

Comment: What's the intended main font of the document?

Comment: using \usepackage[charter]{mathdesign} results in an error : ! Latex Error : Command '\circledD' already defined

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your last comment. I'm unable to reproduce the last problem you mention, `mathdesign` does not define a `\circledD` command. If this is still an issue, boil your code down to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), and update your question.

Comment: This seems rather to be a duplicate of [How to insert a triple line integral?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13412/5645) - where the best answer is [write-math.com](http://write-math.com/symbol/?id=3973) :-)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
\usepackage{mdsymbol}
```

or use one of the `new...math` fonts.

Comment: I'm not sure about `mdsymbol`: it provides symbols designed to accompany sans serif fonts.

Answer (score 0):

As Tobjorn already mentioned (I am too slow), you can add the charter option to `mathdesign`:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}  
\begin{flalign}
\oiiint \rho dv
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Other possible fonts are listed in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mathdesign/doc/mathdesign-doc.pdf) on page 2.