# oiint using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, integral

How can I properly design a symbol, such as `\oiint` with Tikz?

I've found something like this on the internet

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\[
\oint\iint
{\tikz \node[draw, ellipse, inner xsep=-3.6pt, inner ysep=-9pt] {$\displaystyle\iint$};}
\]

\end{document}
```

Which outpouts

[image]

and has a vertical misalignment and doesn't work with subscripts. How can I fix this? Also, how can i change the ellipse's thinkness?

Comment: Just to make sure: you know that there are packages which provide `\oiint`?

Comment: They're all ugly.. I like stix one but I don't want the whole package so I'm trying to reproduce it.

Comment: Maybe you could import the stix symbol https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/36296

Comment: That isn't very well explained also I use pdfTex so I don't think this applies to my case.

Comment: The ellipse's thickness is easily adjusted. Use a [different linewidth for the node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106743/16595). Though I would approach this differently by drawing an explicit ellipse instead of using a shape with negative inner seps.

Comment: Your code needs `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath}` to be compilable, I think. But to solve your problem: add `anchor=base, baseline` to the `\tikz` command, so that it becomes `\tikz[anchor=base, baseline]`. This adjusts the contents of the node to the baseline of the surrounding stuff.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/622906

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are probably better ways.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\oiint}{%
  \mathop{}\!%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \sbox0{$\displaystyle\phantom{\iint}$}%
      \makebox[\wd0]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node[
            line width=0.5pt,
            draw,
            ellipse,
            inner xsep=-0.15ex,
            inner ysep=-0.15ex,
          ] {\phantom{+\,}};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
    }%
  }}\!%
  \iint
}

\begin{document}

\[
\oint_{X} \quad \iint_X \quad \oiint_X
\]

\[
X\iint X
\]

\[
X\oiint X
\]

\end{document}
```

The idea is to insert an empty mathop in order to get the right spacing before the symbol; then we insert a negative thin space because we add an ordinary symbol, namely the ellipse set to a zero width box that has inside it a box as wide as the integral, containing the ellipse. Next another negative thin space to cancel the one that's inserted in front of `\iint`. Thus limits will be appended to `\iint`.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The solution without usage of TikZ can be:

```
\def\circle{.5 0 m .5 .276 .276 .5 0 .5 c -.276 .5 -.5 .276 -.5 0 c
                  -.5 -.276 -.276 -.5 0 -.5 c .276 -.5 .5 -.276 .5 0 c }
\protected\def\oiint{%
  \mathop{\vcenter{
     \pdfliteral{q 10 0 0 6 7 0 cm .06 w \circle S Q}
       }}\!\iint
}

test:
$$
  \oint, \iint_X, \oiint_X
$$
```

The `\pdfliteral` is pdfTeX primitive. You can define
`\def\pdfliteral#1{\special{pdf:literal #1}}` in XeTeX or `\def\pdfliteral{\pdfextension literal}` in LuaTeX.

Comment: I have no idea what that does, but that does the job lol. Could you at least explain how to change the dimensions of the ellipse? So i can do the same with `\oiiint`.

Comment: @Nolord the width of the ellipse is 10, the height is 6 and the shift is 7 bp. If you want to draw an ellipse over `\iiint`, try `15 0 0 6 9 0 cm`. The `cm` PDF operator sets the current matrix of linear transformation.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm gonna accept the other answer because of what I asked, but I'll definitely use your method.

Comment: Do you know any way to adapt the macro to different sizes?